# Bash script, print filenames that contain a string

Tags: bash

I have a folder with a couple of files that I need to organize/manipulate depending on if they both exist, or only one of them exists.

In my folder called `folder1/checkthese/*.bam` the files are:

```
file1_aln.bam
file1_aln_sorted.bam
```

I have a script that checks if I have the unsorted file (which is just `*_aln.bam`) and sorted file (`*_aln_sorted.bam`) but I am having trouble getting my script to run correctly depending on if they both exist or not.

Here is my mini script:

```
for files in folder1/checkthese/*.bam 
do
    if [[ ${files} =~ "_aln.bam" ]] && [[ ${files} =~ "_aln_sorted.bam" ]]
    then                                                                                                                                                                                                         
          echo "both files exist, need to delete unsorted file only"
          echo "REMOVE $(basename ${files/_aln*}_aln.bam)"
          rm -f ${files/_aln*}_aln.bam            
    elif [[ ${files} =~ "_aln_sorted.bam" ]] && [[ ! ${files} =~ "_aln.bam" ]]                                                        
    then                                                                   
          echo "Only sorted file exists, all good"                             
    fi 
done
```

But this is the output I get:

```
Only sorted file exists, all good.
```

But clearly the unsorted file exists so for some reason it is skipping the first part of my loop and not removing the `_aln.bam` file. I am not sure how to change my conditional statement in my elif statement so that if ONLY the `_aln_sorted.bam` file exists, then all is good and I don't need to delete anything.
I think I should not be using the `&&` for my `elif` statement, but I thought the `!` essentially is the `NOT` boolean for this.

Comment: `$files` only has one filename at a time.

Comment: But if I echo $files, it will output both filenames for me no problem.

Comment: `[ ${files} =~ "_aln.bam" ]] && [[ ${files} =~ "_aln_sorted.bam" ]]` can thus never be true, as a single file can't simultaneously have both suffixes.

Comment: Quotes matter. `echo "$files"` to see the true contents of the variable, and keep in mind that it only has one value at a time. If it has one value and then the other later, that won't make the test be true as it's written here.

Comment: Oh I see...ah that makes sense actually. I need to manipulate the filename more within the curly brackets then. however I think I originally did that and ran into issues - I will update my question to show what I mean.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I got it to work with you pointing out the boolean mistake I made. I have updated my script to show what I changed. Originally I had this edited script but mixed up a boolean statement. Derp!!

Comment: Please accept some answer (maybe your own) making clear this question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Dude, your comparision can't do what you want.

Your first comparision is checking for the files that name contains both _aln.bam and _aln_sorted.bam string! And the second is checking for the files that name contains _aln_sorted.bam and doesn't contain _aln.bam!

So these comparions works on same file in every execution!

You need this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /full_path/folder1/checkthese/*.bam 
do
    if [[ ${file} =~ "_aln.bam" ]]
    then                                                                                                                                                                                                         
          echo "Unsorted file was found! It will be removed!"
          echo "Removing the file named ${file}"
          rm -f ${file}
      echo "File removed!"
    elif [[ ${file} =~ "_aln_sorted.bam" ]]                                                        
    then                                                                   
     echo "${file} is a sorted file!"
    fi 
done
```

Comment: Yea I realized that afterwards - still not an expert in bash scripting lol. I was looking for true strings didn't realize I was looking for a file being two names at once.

Answer (score 0):

-----------EDIT--------------------

Okay I fixed my original script which did not use booleans to check for strings in the filename but instead checked if files existed. This worked for me:

Originally I had this script as well but ran into similar problems:

```
for files in folder1/checkthese/*.bam 
do
    if [ -f ${files/_aln*}_aln.bam ] && [ -f ${files/_aln*}_aln_sorted.bam ]
    then                                                                                                                                                                                                         
          echo "both files exist, need to delete unsorted file only"
          echo "REMOVE $(basename ${files/_aln*}_aln.bam)"
          rm -f ${files/_aln*}_aln.bam            
    elif [ -f ${files/_aln*}_aln_sorted.bam ] && [ ! -f ${files/_aln*}_aln_sorted.bam ]                                                    
    then                                                                   
          echo "Only sorted file exists, all good"                             
    fi 
done
```

Output works now.

Answer (score 0):

I will present a little less conventional solution, stressing two points:

- prefer working with file lists like with other textual data
- separate the logic and destructive operations (you can check what you're about to delete)

First create some test files

```
mkdir data
seq 1 5 | xargs -I{} touch 'data/file_{}_aln.bam'

# first three of them have their sorted equivalents
seq 1 3 | xargs -I{} touch 'data/file_{}_aln_sorted.bam'
```

First let's check what files I'd delete:

```
find data -name '*.bam' | sort | sed 's/_sorted//' | uniq -d
```

The complement are the files I have to sort yet:

```
find data -name '*.bam' | sort | sed 's/_sorted//' | uniq -u
```

After checking, I can do something like this to delete the files

```
find data -name '*.bam' | sort | sed 's/_sorted//' | uniq -d | xargs rm
```

The final check if all unsorted are gone can be done easily by

```
ls data/*_aln.bam 

# or to get some numeric results:
ls data/*_aln.bam | wc -l
```

Of course the usual caveats apply - use sensible file names or you have to use `find -print0 | xargs -0` and deal with the consequences.